# Image being saved from canvas is not rendered properly

Tags: c#, image, canvas, windows-phone-8.1, windows-rt

I'm trying to use the following code to save the contents of myCanvas as an image file in the gallery (for Windows Phone 8.1, not Silverlight). When I run the App, the image is saved but it is distorted. What am I doing wrong?  I have uploaded the resultant image and the expected result.

[image]

```
public async void SaveFileToPhone()
  {
      var file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("bug.png", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

     await SaveVisualElementToFile(myCanvas, file);          
  }

async Task SaveVisualElementToFile(FrameworkElement element, StorageFile file)
{
    var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(element, (int)element.Width, (int)element.Height);
    var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
    txt_bug.Text = "Width: " + (int)element.Width + " Height:" + (int)element.Height;

    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        var encoder = await
            BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
        byte[] bytes = pixels.ToArray();

        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                             BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                             (uint)element.Width, (uint)element.Height,
                             96, 96, bytes);

        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

The XAML code for canvas is as follows:

```
<Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" Background="#FF33FFE3" Margin="25,75,26,10" 
ManipulationStarted="myCanvas_ManipulationStarted" 
ManipulationCompleted="myCanvas_ManipulationCompleted" 
ManipulationDelta="myCanvas_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="All" 
Tapped="myCanvas_Tapped" MinHeight="555" MinWidth="350" Width="350" Height="555">
    <Canvas.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0 0 350 555"/>
    </Canvas.Clip>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The params to the `SetPixelData` method are incorrect.

```
encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                         BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                         (uint)element.Width, (uint)element.Height,
                         96, 96, bytes);
```

Change them to the follow can make it work.

```
encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
                (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
                DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
                DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
                bytes);
```

You can download the [XAML render to bitmap sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-render-to-bitmap-dd4f549f) from MSDN for reference.